# Elementor contact forms get marked as spam (good leads, not spam mails)

Tags: wordpress, smtp, elementor

In regard to a global problem on our websites. There is a problem while sending our contact forms via Elementor forms to our our clients email.

They send correctly, but the mailboxes mark them as spam, so they enter the spam folder (the good mails from leads). Our clients have exchange or basic mailboxes (Combell). We've put our settings right.

- SPF-record Basic mailbox ( v=spf1 include:_spf.relay.mailprotect.be -all )
- Exchange mailbox SPF: v=spf1 include:_spf.powermail.be -all

But they ask us the next to do:
"Then make sure that the contact forms send e-mails via the server smtp-auth.mailprotect.be over port 2525. The default port 25 will not work."

Any third-party plugin that's compatible with Elementor forms, or a setting I can make,...?

Answer (score 0):

Install WP Mail SMTP and configure it to send using SendinBlue.

SendinBlue is free for up to 300 mail for day. If that doesn't work, send emails using Google. That should avoid the spam folder.